# Incompatibility Rails 6 ActionText w/ Tailwind webpack installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, tailwind-css, actiontext

After installing Tailwind rich_text_area isn't showing correctly in forms.
Exist a conflict between Rails6 ActionText and tailwind webpacker installation

*There's a trick to fix this error?
Thanks in advance!*

**Expected behavior**
form.rich_text_area showing a text area w/ TRIX editor in view.html.erb

**Actual behavior**
Appearing a simple blank square in the area

**Configuration**

- Debian 9
- Apache-MariaDB
- Phusion Passenger 6.0.4
- rvm: 1.29.9
- Ruby: 2.6.4p104
- Rails: 6.0.0
- Node: v8.16.2
- Webpacker: 4.0.7
- Yarn: 1.19.0
- Tailwind CSS v1.1
- Vue.js 2.9.6

Following the official guide:
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html

```
model.rb
has_rich_text :content
new/edit form
form.rich_text_area :content
view.html.erb
@message.content
```

Comment: TEST DONE: Presently, installing Tailwind in a fresh RAILS 6.0.1 installation you lost the ActiveStorage rich_text_area functionality. Surely the reason is in setting TRIX.js

Comment: Corinn Pope is proving this solution: https://corinnpope.com/development/2020/01/23/rails-6-action-text-tailwind.html but it's also not working for me. resulting error: undefined method `body' for #<String

Comment: woot woot! thanks for that link